# Counting clicks with jQuery and displaying with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I'm hacking away at some code in order to have it register a click on an invisible div element, which expands an article to reveal it's excerpt while adding a +1 to the number of time's it's been clicked by anyone. Afterwards it updates an element with ajax with the number of clicks it's received.

At least, that's the goal.

The following code ends up breaking Wordpress and gives me the white screen of doom. This is taken from a simple click counter with an Ajax callback to update the number.

Where my problem lies is hacking away at this for it to register clicks on a different element.

Without wasting too much of anyones time, here's my question:

Wouldn't I just need to rename all `post_like` to `post_reader`? Someone's been telling my in person that it `should work so check your server` but that is ridiculous... it seems.

Note, below where you see `post_reader`, it had said `post_like` previously.

```
// post click to expand button

$timebeforerevote = 1;

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_post-like', 'post_reader');
add_action('wp_ajax_post-like', 'post_reader');

wp_localize_script('like_post', 'ajax_var', array(
    'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-nonce')
));

function post_like()
{
    $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];

    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'ajax-nonce' ) )
        die ( 'Busted!');

    if(isset($_POST['post_reader']))
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

        $meta_IP = get_post_meta($post_id, "voted_IP");

        $voted_IP = $meta_IP[0];
        if(!is_array($voted_IP))
            $voted_IP = array();

        $meta_count = get_post_meta($post_id, "votes_count", true);

        if(!hasAlreadyVoted($post_id))
        {
            $voted_IP[$ip] = time();

            update_post_meta($post_id, "voted_IP", $voted_IP);
            update_post_meta($post_id, "votes_count", ++$meta_count);

            echo $meta_count;
        }
        else
            echo "already";
    }
    exit;
}

function hasAlreadyVoted($post_id)
{
    global $timebeforerevote;

    $meta_IP = get_post_meta($post_id, "voted_IP");
    $voted_IP = $meta_IP[0];
    if(!is_array($voted_IP))
        $voted_IP = array();
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(in_array($ip, array_keys($voted_IP)))
    {
        $time = $voted_IP[$ip];
        $now = time();

        if(round(($now - $time) / 60) > $timebeforerevote)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function getPostReadLink($post_id)
{
    $themename = "toolbox";

    $vote_count = get_post_meta($post_id, "votes_count", true);

    $output = '<div class="post-read">';
    if(hasAlreadyVoted($post_id))
        $output .= ' <span title="'.__('I like this article', $themename).'" class="qtip like alreadyvoted"></span>';
    else
        $output .= '<a href="#" data-post_id="'.$post_id.'">
                    <span  title="'.__('I like this article', $themename).'"class="qtip like"></span>
                </a>';
    $output .= '<span class="count">'.$vote_count.'</span></div>';

    return $output;
}
```

**The function called when clicked:**

```
jQuery(".expand").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    readers = jQuery(this);

    // Retrieve post ID from data attribute
    post_id = readers.data("post_id");

    // Ajax call
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: ajax_var.url,
        data: "action=post-reader&nonce="+ajax_var.nonce+"&post_reader=&post_id="+post_id,
        success: function(count){
            // If vote successful
            if(count != "already")
            {
                heart.addClass("readered");
                heart.siblings(".count").text(count);
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
})
```

**Invoking it within the appropriate div.**

```
<?php echo getPostReadLink(get_the_ID());?>
```

Comment: You should check your server error logs to see the error that is giving you a white screen. It will tell you if you have a syntax error or are calling a nonexistent function, or anything like that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'd have posted any suspicious error logs if I had any. I've since tried changin all refferences to `like` with `read` and the `.expand` to ensure the right item is being clicked on. Now Wordpress loads, but the page only loads a portion, leaving the rest white...

Comment: If your page is turning white halfway down.. it usually means the error is happening right there. Can you tell what is called right when it turns white? Which log did you check? It's strange there is nothing logged when things turn white like that. Is your `ini` set to display errors at all? You might want to try that during debugging.  

Sidenote: You can make `data` pass an object so you don't have to urlencode yourself.

Comment: `urlencode`? Sounds interesting...

Comment: Mixing up the JS and PHP functions ;) But basically you can turn `data:'a=1&b=2'` to `data: { a: 1, b: 2}`

Comment: Cool. Reminds me of jQuery selectors. Can you tell me in what context that would benefit the above code? -- Also, the error console in Chrome isn't giving me anything I'm aware of that can work easily... unfortunately. To see what I'm doing live if you like you can see it here: theciv.com/vancouver

Comment: Just makes the code cleaner, easier to manage, don't need to escape things. Do you have `firebug` With that on I immediately see a number of JS errors

Comment: `wp_localize_script` is just dumped in the middle of the code. It has to be encapsulated on a proper hook for it to work without glitches.