# Simple way to count clicks with jquery, mysql and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

My question to save time:

What is the simplest way to count clicks of a button, save that value to a Wordpress MySQL db and retrieve that updated total number into a div with Ajax, so the page doesn't need to up reloaded to see it?

I'm just learning how to dive into more UX glory with added mysql db support and Ajax updates with jQuery as the driving force.

My knowledge of working with databases in general is... green to say the least.

I have another question going, but I thought I'd open this up as a more general question. I see lots of tutorials online, but not a lot of elegant, minimal code like I know I've learnt here on SO already.

OP is here: [Counting clicks with jQuery and displaying with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478150/counting-clicks-with-jquery-and-displaying-with-ajax)

Comment: What have you tried ? Also, why do you want to show the count on screen in real-time ? If you don't need to show it in real-time, Google Analytics is an alternative.

Comment: I'd like to count the clicks on certain elements (articles) which are on the same page. This is so other users can see what has been read as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the button's click event and then tell your server-side logic to increment the count in the database, like this:

```
$("#YourButton").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/PathToServerSide',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {increment: true},
        success: function(data) { 
            alert('Server click count updated!') 
        }
    });
}
```

Note: Never trust the client-side to tell the server-side what the count value is, but instead send a command (`increment`) to tell the server-side logic to increment the value in the database.

To display the amount of clicks, use the `data` returned from the AJAX `success` callback and the jQuery `.html()` function, like this:

```
$('#YourCounter').html('The button has been clicked ' + data + ' times`);
```

Comment: sending a command is as insecure as telling the count IMHO

Comment: @DevZer0 - it is not a security issue in this context, but rather a concurrency issue; where browser A and browser B both send the same counter value and the database value is not incremented correctly. For something like banking, then I would agree with your comment.

Comment: This is so much more simple than what I've been trying! But, does this update to the DB? I see the `/PathToServerSide`, but I'm unsure as to what that does so far... Still learning!

Comment: @canacast you have to write your server script.

Comment: @canacast - I did not include any PHP script, as I know nothing about PHP, but I would suggest Googling or asking another question about how to use jQuery `.ajax()` function to call a PHP script and save values to a MySQL database. If you feel my answer was helpful, then feel free to accept and/or up-vote it. :-)

Comment: Done! Not sure why everyone is down voting this. Seems like a viable question to ask.